# extract elements of a list and putting elements in another list, if I want to have the first pairs of a common second pair in general

Tags: python-3.x

In python,How can I extract elements of a list and putting elements in another list, if I want to have the first pairs of a common second pair in general, so the first pairs can be a lists that have 1 pair or more and the second pairs must be only 1 pair
for example, if I have below list:

```
X=[ [[1, 6], [1, 6]], [[1, 6], [1, 7]], [[2, 7], [1, 7]], [[2, 7], [2, 7]], [[2, 4], [1, 4]], [[2, 4], [1, 5]], [[2, 4], [1, 6]]]
```

I want this output in general not only for this example:

```
X1=[ [[[1,6],[2,4]],[1,6]] , [[[1,6],[2,7]],[1,7]] , [[2,7],[2,7]] , [[2,4],[1,4]] , [[2,4],[1,5]] ]
```

Comment: Could you explain your question with a bit easier example? Not sure I understand :)

Comment: suppose that we have a list that is consist of  pairs of another lists such as this x=[[[a,b],[c,d]],[[e,f],[c,d]],..]  and the i want to extract first pairs of common second pairs x1=[[[[a,b],[e,f]],[c,d]],...], and then i need them to use another part of my program, for example i need to know the length of pairs that was related to each pairs, so in this example there are 2 pairs [a,b] and [e,f] that are related to [c,d]